# BigCommerce Templating - How to grab a list of all products

Tags: bigcommerce, templating, bigcommerce-stencil-cli

I'm working on a custom Product Selector page for BigCommerce, and the first step is to grab a list of all the products on the site.

For the life of me, I can't find out information on how to do this.

Is there a way to grab a list of all items, and their custom variables set in the system?

Answer (score 1):

To confirm, you would like to get the products on the storefront itself rather than backend, correct? If so you would benefit from GraphQL APIs to [paginate products](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/graphql-storefront/reference#definition-SearchProducts). You could try them on the graphQL playground of the sample store [here](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/graphql-storefront/playground) or in your own store by navigating from the settings.